# Why does Surah 109:6 say دين and not ديني?

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic

Surah 109:6 "لَكُمْ دِينُكُمْ وَلِيَ دِينِ"

The ayah starts with "to you is your (plural) religion" using the second person plural possessive suffix, while the possessive suffix is not used in the second part of the ayah. Instead of ولي ديني we find ولي دين i.e a more literal translation would be "To you is your religion and to me is a religion".

What are the semantic nuances that such formation carries? Why was the first person singular possessive suffix dropped? What do other Muslim scholars and commentators say about this?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: @RandomUser: Can you mention the source you picked it from?

Comment: Because in my translation it states that it should be as you mention it "To you is your religion and to me is a religion?" I think it's a typo in the Quranic text you read.

Comment: @Tarik what's your source then?

Comment: http://al-quran.info/#109

Comment: In the link I mentioned the translation of the ayat is " To you your religion, to me my religion." As you can see the translator made an distinction between the pronoun and possessive pronoun.

Comment: @Tarik The translation included is my own. Instead of "to me is my religion" I wrote "to me is a religion" because that is the crux of the question -- there is no possessive suffix on the word دين.  Translations say "my religion", as if it were "ديني", but it is only "دين", even in your own link.

Comment: Oké, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @Tarik Oh I see what you meant, with writing "your" twice. Yeah that was a typo. Corrected it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Both meanings are valid and one needs to check whether the Qur'an actually clearly excludes one.

Comment: There is a snippet on this in [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura109-aya6.html) and others.

Answer (score 2):

1- Check out the diacritic undeneath ن. It is Kasrarh" ِِِِ "
Yet, at the end of a sentence in Arabic, diacritics are silent.

2- Majority of scholars said it is pronounced Din without ي. Three scholars (3) Said that it is pronounced " Dini "ديني as it is a noun like Kaf in دينكم" Dinkum". However, when reading Quran, it is noticeable that there are verses with words without the alphabet Ya ي such as the verse here 'فهو 'يهدين' فاتقوا الله 'وأطيعون.

My answer is based on this source: 
http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura109-aya6.html